# Insert Cell above based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, insert, copy

I found this script on here and modified it some to fit my needs. However, I cannot figure out how to insert one cell instead of the entire row

```
Sub BlankLine()
  Dim Col As Variant
  Dim Col2 As Variant
  Dim BlankRows As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim R As Long
  Dim StartRow As Long

  Col = "A"
  Col2 = "B"
  StartRow = 2
  BlankRows = 1

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With ActiveSheet
    For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
      If .Cells(R, Col) <> .Cells(R, Col2) Then
        .Cells(R, Col2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
      End If
    Next R
  End With Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So, if column A does not match Column B at any given row insert a space then keep going with the compare adding one row above any false value.

```
Example: 1 1
         2 3
         3 4

Becomes: 1 1
         2
         3 3
           4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change the If .Cells(R, Col) <> .Cells(R, Col2) Then
    .Cells(R, Col2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp to 

If .Cells(R, Col) <> .Cells(R, Col2) Then
    .Cells(R, Col2).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Will need to play with the order. I can look after I get to work if no one else does.

Comment: For R = StartRow To LastRow seems to work better although depending on your dataset it still might cause problems.

Comment: Col and Col2 aren't really Variants...you are using them as strings.

Comment: Quick clarification: if there are two rows off, such as col one has `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` vertically and col two only has `1`, `5`; would you still only want one space? Or were you wanting it to be bumped down to the matching number?

Comment: @partyhatpanda Ideally, I would like it insert rows until it column A matches column B. However, depending on my dataset I could see that going horribly wrong lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Cells(R, Col2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: I tried that..."Run-time error '1004': Insert method of Range class failed"

Comment: @TylerYoc - What was the value of R and Col2 when it gave the error?  (I assume the error **was** on the changed line.)

Comment: @YowE3K I dont get it. When the current cell ( `Cells(R, Col2)` ) is shifted down, the blank cell is indeed inserted above. Anyway, I wanted to indicate to the OP how to insert *"not an entire row"*, it seems to me that was the main question. Now it is turning into an *XY* problem.

Comment: I don't think I had thought my previous comment through, i.e. I saw that, when it decided that 3<>4, it would generate 1, 3, empty, 4 rather than 1, empty, 3, 4.  But it really needs to flip the loop around to make it actually give what the OP wants.

Comment: @YowE3K I totally agree and I realized it. the loop should go from the top down. But again, lol, a typical XY.

Comment: I suspect that the actual problem that needs to be solved in this situation will require blanks to be inserted into **both** columns.  (I am always doing that sort of thing myself, and I would love it if I could find a programmatic solution - effectively something similar to DOS's `FC` command, but working on two columns in Excel.   Hmmm, maybe I could export the two columns to text files, do a `FC`, piping the output to another text file, then import that result file back into Excel.  Oooh - something to play with!)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your loop from:

```
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
    If .Cells(R, Col) <> .Cells(R, Col2) Then
       .Cells(R, Col2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next R
```

to

```
For R = StartRow To LastRow
    If .Cells(R, Col).Value <> .Cells(R, Col2).Value Then
        .Cells(R, Col2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next R
```

A word of warning - if you data looks like this:

```
Example: 1 3
         2 1
         3 2
```

it will end up looking like this:

```
Becomes: 1 
         2
         3 3
           1
           2
```

so make sure your data is in a sensible sequence before using this.

Comment: Yes, I definitely see the problem there. And that worked as expected. Thank you very much.